# How I get logs for the install4j IDE?

Tags: ide, install4j

I'm opening an install4j project from 5.0 in 5.1.5, and a dialog box states

> Error loading configuration: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

If I save this project, the size drops from 44kB to 20kB.

How do I figure out what's going wrong? A stack trace would be a great start...

Answer (score 2):

I found /tmp/install4j_error.log which showed the stack trace.

It seems that my ${compiler:basedir} variable is causing an issue since it's unspecified in the variables list...

Comment: (and since basedir does not begin with "sys." I presume install4j was previously being lenient on our misconfiguration) http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/variables.html